# sometimes java client socket does not throw exception while writing data on socket during non availability of internet connection

Tags: java, sockets, client

In java client socket programming, I am trying to get exception in the case where user  writes data on socket when internet connection is not available.Most of the time I get IoException while writing in this situation but sometime I  dont get any exception in this case.
Can anyone tell me where that data goes when any Exception does not arise.

Answer (score 0):

It goes into the socket send buffer in the kernel. In general you won't get an exception on the first write after an outage, because of this buffer. You'll get it on a subsequent write, when the kernel has had time to time out trying to send the data in the buffer.

Comment: Thanks but even after subsequent writes i am not getting any exception.what can be the reason??